# Execute command on master when a state has been applied to all minions in SaltStack

Tags: python, salt-stack

I have a state which I am applying to all minions. The state basically copies required files from the minions using cp.push .
I then want to execute a command only on master where it will zip all those files.
How is this possible?
Is it possible using saltstack Reactor or Runners.

Comment: You may use reactor, runner or install minion into your salt master to do that.

Comment: I think a custom runner as outlined in this blog will work. I don't have time to put together a working example right now.. https://codehammer.io/blog/post/saltstack-highstate-email-alerts/

Comment: Used a runner finally. Thanks.